# AWS S3 Images Uploaded to Rails via Paperclip Opening Locally, but not in Production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a bucket set up on AWS S3 so I can upload images via paperclip.  It's working perfectly on my Localhost, but in production the images ARE being uploaded to the bucket, but are not showing up.  I have it narrowed down to the link that's being generated.  The one that is being generated by rails isn't the same as the link that I see when I actually find the photo in the AWS folder structure.

**Generated Link:**
http://s3.amazonaws.com/ocrphotobucket/blogs/images/000/000/001/original/53600574_l.jpg?1493660602

**Good Link:**
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ocrphotobucket/blogs/images/000/000/001/original/53600574_l.jpg

I have searched many similar SO posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469943/rails-4-carrierwave-aws-images-uploaded-to-amazon-s3-locally-but-not-in-produ) and this), but nothing has worked.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

I have this in my `production.rb`:

```
  # AWS
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
  }
```

And I assume all my credentials are correct in Heroku, as the images are being uploaded.  Thoughts?

**UPDATE**
I double checked that all my credentials were correct in Heroku (they are) and I renamed the bucket not to include underscores (links above changed accordingly, but not otherwise).  The problem persists.

Comment: Don't assume that your creds are correct!  Go into Heroku's settings tab for your app and look at the environment vars you've added to make sure they match.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I double checked in the Heroku settings and everything is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up posting the line `s3_host_name: 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com'` in my `production.rb` code, between storage and s3 credentials, which fixed the problem.

Comment: Is it not a problem with CORS ? I had the same issue with a page with some JavaScript in it. Image was broken. Some other images on the app were working fine though... Not sure why cross site assets usage was triggering broken images. JS seems one. (My app is deployed to Heroku, with an S3 bucket too with paperclip uploads)

Comment: Sorry seems ok now for you